# Adding styles to a specific header cell in AgGrid

Tags: css, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am working on AgGrid (`AgGridReact` component) with one of the header cells having a checkbox for 'select all'

[image: Please refer the image here]

Was wondering if there is a way to pad/margin the select-all checkbox in alignment with the checkboxes in the column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `headerClass` to a specific column definition and apply the css style as usual

```js
const columnDefs = [
  {
    checkboxSelection: true,
    headerCheckboxSelection: true,
    headerClass: "checkbox",
    width: 70
  },
  {
    headerName: "ID",
    field: "id",
    width: 70
  },
  ...
}
```

**Css**

```css
/* add role attribute to increase specificity */
.ag-header-cell.checkbox[role="presentation"] {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64273758/adding-padding-margin-to-a-specific-header-cell-in-ag-grid]